# Submit function does not seem to work

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to append to some text to my html and using the `submit()` doesn't seem to be working. I am also getting a strange message from jquery that `toLowerCase` is not a function. All the other scripts are commented out to make sure there is no interference.

Jquery:

```
var template = function(action){
    return '<div class="event"><p>'+ action +'</p></div>'
};
var display = function(input){
    var temp = input;
    if(temp !== "") {
        $('html').appendTo('.gameboard');
    } else {
         prompt("You need to imput an appropriate answer");
    }
    $('#action').val("");
};

var main = function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var action = $('#action').val();
        var input = action.toLowerCase();
        var html = template(action);
        display(action);
        interact(input);
        return false;
    });

};

$(document).ready(main);
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lord of the Deahsticks</title>
    <link href="css/text-game.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="info">
    <h1 class="title">Lord of the Deathsticks</h1>
</div>

<div class="gameboard">
    <div class="event">
        <p>Hello this is the game!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="event">
        <p>You are awoken by a sound...You need to get up already, you're going to be late for you shift at the slave factory!</p>
    </div>

</div>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="#action" name="what to do">
    <input type="submit" name="button">
</form>
<script src="js/controllers/controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/model/characters.js"></script>
<script src="js/JQuery/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/JQuery/text-game-JQuery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should always post the exact error message you're receiving; that conveys important, relevant information. "doesn't seem to be working" and "strange message" are not as helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to append content when submit button is clicked.

When a form is submitted, the default browser action is to reload the page. So, you have to override the default browser behaviour using `preventDefault` on the `event` object.

Also remove the pound symbol in the value of `id` attribute.

```
<input type="text" id="#action" name="what to do">
```

In your display method, you're appending the string 'html' and not the actual `html` content which is held in the variable `temp`. Modify your display method to

```
var display = function(input){
if(input !== "") {
 var html = template(input);
$(html).appendTo('.gameboard');
} else {
     alert("You need to input an appropriate answer");
}
$('#action').val("");
```

};

Note that we are calling the `template` method inside the display method only if the user entered something. And then we append the html content in the variable `html` to the class `gameboard`.

Your main method should look like

```
var main = function(){
  $('form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $('#action').val();
    var input = action.toLowerCase();
    display(action);
    interact(input);
    return false;
  });
};
```

Working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWQwvm

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and explanations! Helped me understand what I'm trying to do so much more!

Answer (score 0):

"Also, my test html pages is in a refresh loop and I cannot seem the find the problem."
If you submit a form, it will refresh the page :

```
 $('form').submit();
```

So :

```
$(document).ready(main);
var main = function(){
    $('form').submit();
    ...
};
```

Will refresh the page once loaded, so will load it continuously.
I'm not sure about your goal concerning the submit action.

Comment: when I was reading over my code I just realised that, changed it and the reloading is gone!

Comment: Also check the `appendTo()` part ;)

Comment: I thought the content precedes the method when using appendTo instead of append. Also when the text input is submitted or clicked I want i to appear as a div in the screen

Answer (score 0):

Remove # from the id

```
 <input type="text" id="#action" name="what to do">
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="action" name="what to do">
```